# Android Studio: open file operation failed (The open file operation failed to connect to the open and save panel service.)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been using Android studio for quite a while now, but one day the application just suddenly go wrong. When I try to click on my directories to find the files to import or open, the application gets incredibly slow and not responsive at all. When I finally successfully switch to the intended directory where my file is stored, the directory doesn't show anything that can be opened (as shown in the screenshot, where I try to open a file from my download folder but it doesn't show anything).

[image: problem image]

This error message kept showing up as well (open file operation failed: The open file operation failed to connect to the open and save panel service.)

[image: error image]

I have tried to uninstall and re-download Android studio for several times but the problem still remains.

Comment: any solution???

Comment: Same happened to me, please someone help

Answer (score 5):

I'm on the latest macOS beta - I've seen the same issue with Artic Fox build of AS.

I upgraded to the Beta Previews of AS and this issue went away.

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html

Comment: How to fix the issue in the stable android studio?

Answer (score 5):

This is stable WORKAROUND:

1. Launch Android studio (stable)
2. Help - Edit Custom VM Options
3. Put this options `-Dide.mac.file.chooser.native=false`
4. Restart Android studio

Comment: "This is working for me". But  when I tried to create a new key while Signing build when I click on key store path Same Error came

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue. Not sure what is going on, but I'm opening from the command line in the meantime to get to the correct directory:

`open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app /path/to/my_android_project`

Comment: Without terminal how can we resolve the issue?